# Create A count Features right

Tags: python, pandas, feature-engineering

I have a table like that:

| PC | USER | Period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | U1 | 2020/01 |
| A | U2 | 2020/02 |
| A | U3 | 2020/03 |
| A | U4 | 2020/04 |
| B | U1 | 2020/01 |
| B | U2 | 2020/02 |
| B | U2 | 2020/03 |

I need to create a "feature count" to check how many time "PC" found and "user" connected

now for a machine learning algorithm what is the best way to do that?
or even a combination of them

1. for every row show the max connection:

| PC | USER | Period | Max Con Per PC | Max Con Per USER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | U1 | 2020/01 | 4 | 2 |
| A | U2 | 2020/02 | 4 | 3 |
| A | U3 | 2020/03 | 4 | 1 |
| A | U4 | 2020/04 | 4 | 1 |
| B | U1 | 2020/01 | 3 | 2 |
| B | U2 | 2020/02 | 3 | 3 |
| B | U2 | 2020/03 | 3 | 3 |

2. for every row show the COUNT OF the connection:

| PC | USER | Period | Max Con Per PC | Max Con Per USER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | U1 | 2020/01 | 1 | 1 |
| A | U2 | 2020/02 | 2 | 1 |
| A | U3 | 2020/03 | 3 | 1 |
| A | U4 | 2020/04 | 4 | 1 |
| B | U1 | 2020/01 | 1 | 2 |
| B | U2 | 2020/02 | 2 | 2 |
| B | U2 | 2020/03 | 3 | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` then `transform` and `cumcount`:

```
# Use lazy groups
gpc = df.groupby('PC')['PC']
gus = df.groupby('USER')['Period']

df['Max Con Per PC'] = gpc.transform('size')
df['Count Con Per PC'] = gpc.cumcount() + 1
df['Max Con Per USER'] = gus.transform('size')
df['Count Con Per USER'] = gus.cumcount() + 1
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  PC USER   Period  Max Con Per PC  Count Con Per PC  Max Con Per USER  Count Con Per USER
0  A   U1  2020/01               4                 1                 2                   1
1  A   U2  2020/02               4                 2                 3                   1
2  A   U3  2020/03               4                 3                 1                   1
3  A   U4  2020/04               4                 4                 1                   1
4  B   U1  2020/01               3                 1                 2                   2
5  B   U2  2020/02               3                 2                 3                   2
6  B   U2  2020/03               3                 3                 3                   3
```

Comment: thanks but for a machine learning algorithm what is  the best approach. do a combination of the methiod?????

Comment: What do you want to do: classification or regression?

Comment: i what to do a classification thanks !!!

Comment: What is your target column (y)?

Comment: target  columns "is fraud" Yes 1 no 0

Comment: I recommend you post your question at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. I think you will get more answers but I'm not sure you need ML to determine if there is a fraud or not.